# Weighted average with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, weighted-average

I have an API call that returns an array with 'participant_timestamp', 'price', and 'size'.
I am looking for help in calculating a weighted average based on subsets of different time periods within this array.
I've been trying to utilize ma.masked_outside with two 'participant_timestamp' values as the beginning and end of the time period subset, but I'm getting nowhere.
Alternatively, I could use multiple API calls and adjust the time frame parameters for each call, but I'm hoping there's a more efficient way to do the former.

```
##Get Weighted Average Across Full Time Period##
api_data = ##API call specifics##
df = pd.DataFrame(api_data)
weighted_average_all_data = np.average(df['price'], weights=df['size'])
print(weighted_average_all_data)

##Attempt at ma.masked_outside##
new_array = ma.masked_outside(df['participant_timestamp'],15847272000000000000,15847266000000000000)
new_wtd_avg = np.average(new_array['price'], weights=new_array['size'])
print(new_wtd_avg)
```

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: ma.masked_outside returns a masked_array object, but you are trying to index it on the next line using strings. That's likely what is throwing the IndexError. You can read more about the masked_array object here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray . Is there a reason you are not just doing the query with pandas like `df.loc[(df.participant_timestamp < some_value) & (df.participant_timestamp > some_value)]` ?

Comment: @AdamJohnston
Thanks, your suggestion is what I needed!
To your question as to why I wasn't using df.loc[...] the answer is that I am new to Python and didn't know of it.  My Googling head lead me down a path where ma.masked_outside seemed like the right path, but your suggested solution is much better.